# Where can I find the possible codepage parameter values for C++ ICU Unicode?

Tags: c++, unicode, icu, codepages

[ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/) is a library to support internalization. In C++ you have constructors or methods with codepage being a *const char* * parameter.

```
UnicodeString (const char *codepageData, const char *codepage)
```

I understood this is the encoding of your *codepageData*. There's no documentation whatsoever I could find on what are the valid strings for it. I suppose, but that's just a guess, those will be something like:

- UTF-8 or UTF_8 or utf-8 or utf_8
- ASCII or ascii
- .. ans so on

Any idea or link to the list of possible values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this on their site: http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/convexp
(and use the left side names)

For example: US-ASCII

Comment: One can also use the aliases. I only tried ASCII though.